# What does Regular expression denial of service when using npm mean?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-audit

I am new to programming and everyone keeps mentioning how it is problem specific but I wanted to know when using npm audit does the denial of service mean its not able to communicate with the git repository?

```
glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
Regular expression denial of service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/chokidar
    live-server  >=1.2.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/live-server

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS, https://sec.okta.com/articles/2020/04/attacking-evil-regex-understanding-regular-expression-denial-service/, ...

Comment: The npm package `glob-parent` had a bug in a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) that would allow an attacker to perform a [denial of service attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) that could affect your application. The vulnerability was fixed [with this commit](https://github.com/gulpjs/glob-parent/commit/f9231168b0041fea3f8f954b3cceb56269fc6366). Because the version of `chokidar` you're using relies on a version of `glob-parent` that was vulnerable to this issue, npm warns you.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with git or your repository. The [GitHub link](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6) in the warning is the notice about the vulnerability in `glob-parent`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is an alert coming from NPM that reports that one of the packages your project is using, `glob-parent`, had a vulnerability before version 5.1.2. [Specifically](https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JS-GLOBPARENT-1016905), someone could theoretically do:

```
var globParent = require("glob-parent")
function build_attack(n) {
var ret = "{"
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
ret += "/"
}

return ret;
}

globParent(build_attack(5000));
```

or create some other deliberately malformed string for `globParent` to parse, which would result in your system hanging due to a regular expression that glob-parent is using.

If you upgrade to a more recent version of glob-parent (which you can do with `npm audit fix`), you will no longer be vulnerable to this attack

> does the denial of service mean its not able to communicate with the git repository?

No, it means that a bad actor could theoretically leverage glob-parent to deny resources to your system (until you killed the process). It doesn't mean that such a thing is actually taking place, just that the old versions of glob-parent were vulnerable to such a thing.